# Incorporating Jazzy documentation generator with Fastlane

Tags: swift, documentation-generation, fastlane, jazzy, fastfile

I've been able to produce jazzy documentation for my iOS/swift projects and frameworks locally. I'd like to start producing them via Fastlane so that they get updated automatically when they get built on a Jenkins job.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on incorporating jazzy with Fastlane or Jenkins.

Does anyone have any good tutorials or repo examples they can share? Additionally, I'd like to be able to pass something in my Fastfile or config file that uploads it to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It is well documented here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/jazzy/#jazzy

You must specify the path to the `.jazzy.yaml` for the fastlane action.

You can also look at https://github.com/realm/jazzy#usage to figure out what configuration is available for your `.jazzy.yaml` file.

" For a detailed explanation and an exhaustive list of all available options, run `jazzy --help config`."

After you create your lane, call `fastlane YOUR_LANE_NAME` in whatever CI you are using

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I believe I was able to get it configured 

#  lane :build_docs do
#    jazzy(
#       config: ".jazzy.yaml",
#    )
#  end

I wish there was more documentation or tutorials on incorporating with a CI specifically uploading to an S3 bucket

Comment: https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins/#aws_s3


Fastlane as a directory of available plugins from other developers outside the Fastlane team. If all else fails there's documentation on how to make your own Plugin to achieve the task you want.

Overall, Fastlane is documented well